# Trying to access Lotus DB via Java application - getting error msg " XXX.nsf has not been opened yet"

Tags: java, lotus-notes

I'm trying to connect to a Lotus DB from an external Java application - my code works perfectly against a database located on my test (local) server, but fails when run against the production DB (no data is returned).

`Diiop` is running on the production server, and I have  editor access for the production DB.

I'm able to create a session with the Domino server through my Java code, but am not able to open the Lotus DB.

```
Session session = NotesFactory.createSession("<Server>","UserID","password"); 
System.out.println("connected");
Database db = session.getDatabase("Server","<DB Path>" );
System.out.println("Access level: "+ db.getCurrentAccessLevel());
View vw = db.getView("Viewname");
```

After creating a session with the Domino server, I attempt to open the database, at which point I get the error `XXX.nsf has not been opened yet`.

I have also tried utilizing the `IsOpen` and `open` methods, with no luck.

Comment: Can you open any database on the server (for example `names.nsf`)? Could you show the relevant parts of your code?

Comment: No i tried with names.nsf as well in my code, but same error 

here is my code ...
.........
Session session=NotesFactory.createSession("<Server>","UserID","password");
System.out.println("connected");
Database db=session.getDatabase("Server","<DB Path>" );
System.out.println("Access level: "+ db.getCurrentAccessLevel());
View vw =db.getView("Viewname");
........

Comment: What, if any, messages are appearing on the Domino server's console and in its log at the moment that you run your code?

Comment: Also, I have to ask...   You're not really passing in "<Server>", are you?

Comment: I dont have access for production servers log. so not able to track log Msg.

Not Yet solved

Answer (score 2):

Your database will not open in Java code, if its ACL forbids Internet access (that means http task). Check advanced tab of ACL, property "Maximum internet name and password". It should be at least Depositor to open it, or Reader to read data from it.

Comment: checked that too its "EDITOR"

Answer (score 2):

For diiop to work, the server has to have the **allow HTTP clients to browse databases** setting enabled. This setting is found in `Server document->Internet Protocols->HTTP->R5 Basics`. Of note,  this setting takes effect even in modern Domino server instances. My guess is that the current value for this setting (set to "no") is where your problem is coming from.

You should also make sure that diiop is configured properly. The first test for this is to access **http://hostname.domain.com/diiop_ior.txt**. Accessing this URL should show you a page containing a simple text string containing something like 32 (seemingly) random characters.

I usually refer to this [page](http://benpoole.com/bp/wiki.nsf/pages/DominoDIIOP) when I need to get diiop working.

Comment: yeah it was "No" . As you said i opened the diiop_ior.txt file with a long random characters, after giving my user name and password.

still getting the same error DB has not been Opened yet

Comment: You did restart HTTP after making the change from No to Yes?

Answer (score 1):

First try to access the database through a browser using the name/password in your code. If that doesn't work either HTTP isn't running or there is another issue separate to your code.

With issues like this I start with the sample code in the Infocenter.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_EXAMPLES_GETDATABASE_METHOD_JAVA.html

eg.

```
Database db = session.getDatabase("<SERVER>", "<DBNAME>");

if (!db.isOpen())

    System.out.println("DB does not exist.");

  else

    System.out.println("Title of database: \"" + db.getTitle()+ "\"") ;
```

See if that prints out anything.

The error message normally means the database is locked by the server, or corrupted. So try another database that you know you must have access to (eg. names.nsf ).

Comment: i'm able to access the db on browser using the same pwd, if it is wrong i shud get error as Invalid user name password... but m not gettin any such error. 
i tried the code that is suggested by simon but getting "DB does not exist" ... 
Tried with different db , Issue is same.

Comment: i tried "getCurrentAccessLevel()" .. though i ve editor access its showing up Access level is  :0

Comment: May i know what you meant by db locked by server?

Comment: For example compact or fix up running.

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity, what does printing :

```
session.getUserName();
```

..just before `getCurrentAccessLevel()` show? Is there an ambiguous username and you're ending up being authenticated as someone you don't expect?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error

```
Database xxx.nsf has not been opened yet
```

My problem was due to using a front slash instead of backslash.  This corrected it:

```
var db = session.getDatabase(session.getServerName(), "path/dbname.nsf");
```

I noticed that nowhere in the above question is the db path identified, so perhaps the wrong slashes are being used.

The irritating part is that instead of returning an error message 'file not found' the NotesException message is `pathdbname.nsf has not been opened yet` when in fact it can't be found...